# Is this patent in the public domain?

Tags: us4475856

I noticed in the Legal Events portion of this patent it says that it has expired due to lack of payment. I was wondering if that entitles anyone and everyone to this idea now that it has expired from the previous patent holder. Is there anyway that I could find myself in a sticky situation using an idea similar in a project of mine?

Answer (score 1):

Once the patent has expired/lapsed, it is indeed put into the public domain.

Of course, someone else may have a current patent on an improved version of the expansion screw, so you're not necessarily in the clear if you're using a similar design.

Comment: Or they may have a patent on some other part of your new design.